# I need to add a column that assigns row numbers to each record

Tags: oracle, row-number, partition-by

I am trying to add a column that assigns row numbers to each record

I made changes to the code to add the desired column

But I was getting duplicated row numbers. How do I get unique row numbers?
.

```
**Note: This code can be executed in the SQL editor like that. It needs no sample data**

select distinct trunc(GenerateTimeBy1Day,'day') as claim_eff_date, trunc(GenerateTimeBy1DayPlus20,'day') as bwe_to_completeby from
(
    select from_dt + (level - 1)/1 as GenerateTimeBy1Day, (from_dt + (level - 1)/1) + 20 as GenerateTimeBy1DayPlus20 
    from (select from_dt
        ,to_dt
        ,to_dt - from_dt + 1 as days_between    
    from (select to_date('03-Jan-2021') as from_dt
               , to_date('30-Jan-2021') as to_dt 
          from dual))
    connect by (level - 1) <= days_between  
)
order by claim_eff_date
```

I made these changes to the code to add the desired column

```
**Note: This code can be executed in the SQL editor like that. It needs no sample data**

select distinct trunc(GenerateTimeBy1Day,'day') as claim_eff_date, trunc(GenerateTimeBy1DayPlus20,'day') as bwe_to_completeby, row_number() 
over (PARTITION BY trunc(GenerateTimeBy1Day,'day'), trunc(GenerateTimeBy1DayPlus20,'day') ORDER BY trunc(GenerateTimeBy1Day,'day')) as row_number from
(
    select from_dt + (level - 1)/1 as GenerateTimeBy1Day, (from_dt + (level - 1)/1) + 20 as GenerateTimeBy1DayPlus20 
    from (select from_dt
        ,to_dt
        ,to_dt - from_dt + 1 as days_between    
    from (select to_date('03-Jan-2021') as from_dt
               , to_date('30-Jan-2021') as to_dt 
          from dual))
    connect by (level - 1) <= days_between  
)
order by claim_eff_date
```

But I am getting

```
Row_Number
----------
1
1
2
3
4
5
6
1
1
2
3
```

How do I get unique row numbers?

```
Row_Number
----------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: If you don't want the number to repeat, don't include a `partition by` clause in your `row_number`.  Just use the `order by` clause.

Comment: If I simply use the order by clause while adding the row_number() as the desired column, I get this error message:

ORA-30484: missing window specification for this function
30484. 00000 -  "missing window specification for this function"
*Cause:    All window functions should be followed by window specification,
           like <function>(<argument list>) OVER (<window specification>)
*Action:
Error at Line: 103 Column: 128

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whet those dates represent, but - if query you initially wrote does the job, then use it as *source* for the final query which calculates row number:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> with your_query as (
  2  select distinct trunc(GenerateTimeBy1Day,'day') as claim_eff_date,
  3                  trunc(GenerateTimeBy1DayPlus20,'day') as bwe_to_completeby
  4  from
  5  (
  6      select from_dt + (level - 1)/1 as GenerateTimeBy1Day, (from_dt + (level - 1)/1) + 20 as GenerateTimeBy1DayPlus20
  7      from (select from_dt
  8          ,to_dt
  9          ,to_dt - from_dt + 1 as days_between
 10      from (select date '2021-01-03' as from_dt
 11                 , date '2021-01-30' as to_dt
 12            from dual))
 13      connect by (level - 1) <= days_between
 14  ))
 15  select claim_eff_date,
 16         bwe_to_completeby,
 17         row_number() over (order by claim_eff_date) rn
 18  from your_query
 19  order by claim_eff_date;

CLAIM_EFF_ BWE_TO_COM         RN
---------- ---------- ----------
28.12.2020 18.01.2021          1
04.01.2021 25.01.2021          2
04.01.2021 18.01.2021          3
11.01.2021 01.02.2021          4
11.01.2021 25.01.2021          5
18.01.2021 08.02.2021          6
18.01.2021 01.02.2021          7
25.01.2021 08.02.2021          8
25.01.2021 15.02.2021          9

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

By the way, this is what you wrote: `to_date('03-Jan-2021')`. That's wrong. `TO_DATE` applied to a string without date format mask relies on Oracle's capabilities to *guess* what you meant to say. Besides, that won't even work in my database, although you said

> This code can be executed in the SQL editor

My database speaks *Croatian* and there's no month like `Jan`.

Safer option is to

- apply format mask: `to_date('03-Jan-2021', 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english')`
- or, use date literal (like I did): `date '2021-01-03'` which ALWAYS has `date` keyword and date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, so there's no ambiguity